# cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.0 "Network Information" not detecting when app is online

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing an ios app in ionic1.
for network connection and dis-connection i am using cordova plugin ie **cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.0 "Network Information"**.

Also my **cordova version 6.4.0**

when I launch app and login with the credentials then I am dis-connecting the wifi connection at that time `OnOffLine event` is fired but after some time I switch on the wifi that time `OnOnLine Event` is not fire.

this is my code.

```
 $scope.onLoad = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
  }

      function onOffline() {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Connection Failed!',
                template: 'Please check your network is running!'
            });
             console.log('onOFFLINE');
        }
        // Handle the online event
        function onOnline() {           
            console.log('onONLINE');// here is problem.
        }
```

onOffline work perfectly when I disconnect wifi onOffline event fires. but when wifi re-connected at that time onOnline event is not getting fired.

Comment: any reply on this I am stuck here from last 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/). To install in ionic refer this [link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)

ngCordova gives you an angular wrapper around the plugin that implements promises.

Here is an example from the ngCordova page on the network plugin [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/).

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()
    var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline()
    var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()

    // listen for Online event
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
      var onlineState = networkState;
    })

    // listen for Offline event
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
      var offlineState = networkState;
    })

  }, false);
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution but its not working.... http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/check-network-information-change-with-ionic-famework/

Comment: Have you tried diagnostics plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#iswifienabled

Comment: does this plugin work for a mobile network such as 2G/3G/4G. or it work only for wifi network